# GeoDmsRun cannot find 'Values' attribute inside Unique values unit, while GUI can

Tags: geography, geodms

In GeoDMS, a geographic coding language by Object Vision, I cannot run code in GeoDmsRun.exe, which I could run without problems in GeoDmsGui.exe. The problem is that it cannot find the parameter 'Values' which is indeed not defined, but apparently implicit somewhere in GeoDMS. The GUI could find this parameter.

I tried defining the Values that lookup is looking for explicitly using

```
attribute<uint32>values1:=values;
```

But that didn't work. It would be best to get this lookup functionality without having to use any implicit variables, but how to do that?

Code:

```
unit<uint32> heatNet2 := unique(buildingWithHeatDemand/roadID) 
,   dialogType = 'map'
,   dialogData = 'geometry'
{
    attribute<rdc> geometry(arc) := lookup(values,input/geographic/roads/geometry);
}
```

Version: 7177

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The `unique(D->V)` operator indeed defines an attribute `E->V` with the name `values` of the resulting unit `E` that maps that resulting unit `E` to the found values of `V`. GeoDmsRun.exe should process scripts the same way as GeoDmsGui.exe does, so it is a good idea to report this as issue at http://www.mantis.objectvision.nl.

Meanwhile you can try to define the values attribute explicitly:

```
unit<uint32> heatNet2 := unique(buildingWithHeatDemand/roadID) 
,   dialogType = 'map'
,   dialogData = 'geometry'
{
    attribute<input/geographic/roads> values(heatNet2);
    attribute<rdc> geometry(arc) := lookup(values,input/geographic/roads/geometry);
}
```

The now explicitly defined `values` will refer to the attribute of the result of the unique operator.

Comment: Thanks, that did fix this problem!

After fixing this, I get the same issue wherever implicit variables are used, such as an [nr_OrgEntity] construction after calling a subset, and with calling dist from a container with connect_info. These can be fixed in a similar way.